# Dynamically call a stored procedure from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to be able to pass in the name of a stored procedure as a string into another stored procedure and have it called with dynamic parameters.  I'm getting an error though.

Specifically I've tried:

```
create procedure test @var1 varchar(255), @var2 varchar(255) as
    select 1

create procedure call_it @proc_name varchar(255)
    as
    declare @sp_str varchar(255)
    set @sp_str = @proc_name + ' ''a'',''b'''
    print @sp_str
    exec @sp_str

exec call_it 'test'
```

So procedure call_it should call procedure test with arguments 'a', and 'b'.

When I run the above code I get:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Procedure call_it, Line 6
>       Could not find stored procedure 'test 'a','b''.

However, running test 'a','b' works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need parentheses

```
exec (@sp_str)
```

if the proc didn't exists the message would be this

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
*Could not find stored procedure 'test'.*

it would not be *Could not find stored procedure 'test 'a','b''*

Although still a bad idea with SQL injection, try using sp_executeSQL and use parameters, see here about query plan reuse: [Changing exec to sp_executesql doesn't provide any benefit if you are not using parameters correctly](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/changing-exec-to-sp_executesql-doesn-t-p)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the "sp_executesql" procedure. Look at [MSDN - sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any kind of dynamic SQL (`EXEC()` or `sp_executesql`) at all to achieve this result:

```
create procedure test @var1 varchar(255), @var2 varchar(255) 
as
BEGIN
    select @var1, @var2;
END;

create procedure call_it @proc_name varchar(255)
as
BEGIN
declare @param1 VARCHAR(255) = 'a'
       ,@param2 VARCHAR(255) = 'b';
exec @proc_name @param1, @param2;  --it isn't dynamic-SQL(simple procedure call)
END;

exec call_it @proc_name = 'test';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f20edb5199fc94e54faf8092e47d189)**

---

From [EXECUTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> ```
> [ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]  
> {   
>   [ @return_status = ]  
>   { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var }
> ```
>
> **@module_name_var**
>
> **Is the name of a locally defined variable that represents a module name.**
>
> This can be a variable that holds the name of a natively compiled, scalar user-defined function.